# Cannot get Bubblewrap data from model to controller

Tags: rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using the latest version of Rubymotion.
I got a tableview that I would like to fill with data from a remote API.

I named the controller: *ProjectsController*

I named the model: *Project*

In the controller viewDidLoad I want to get a list of projects from the API.
I have created a static method in the Project model called load_projects.

```
def self.load_projects
 BW::HTTP.get("#{URL}projects?id=25&project_id=24&access_token=#{TOKEN}") do |response|
  result_data = BW::JSON.parse(response.body)
  output = result_data["projects"]
  output
 end
end
```

This is my viewDidLoad in the controller:

```
def viewDidLoad
 super
 @projects = Project.load_projects
 self.navigationItem.title = "Projekt"
end
```

I do not get the same response in the viewDidLoad as I do in the model. In the model method I get the correct response data but in the viewDidLoad I get a "meta" object returned. A BubbleWrap::HTTP::Query object. What am I doing wrong?

**Update one**

I tried to use the first answer below like this but I get an error:

```
def tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
    cellIdentifier = self.class.name
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) || begin
      cell = UITableViewCell.alloc.initWithStyle(UITableViewCellStyleDefault, reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier)
      cell
    end

    project = @projects[indexPath.row]['project']['title']
    cell.textLabel.text = project
    cell
  end
```

The error is:

```
projects_controller.rb:32:in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
2012-11-09 01:08:16.913 companyapp[44165:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason: 'projects_controller.rb:32:in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I can show the returned data here without errors:

```
def load_data(data)
    @projects ||= data
    p @projects[0]['project']['title']
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

Ha, I just went through the exact same problem.

The solution I got was the following:

The BW::HTTP method is asynchronous, so your self.load_projects method will return a request object, instead of the JSON data that you want.

Essentially the BW:HTTP.get completes execution immediately and the self.load_projects method returns the incorrect data.

The solution that was suggested to me is the following:

Change your load_projects method so it accepts a view controller delegate:

```
def self.load_projects(delegate)
  BW::HTTP.get("#{URL}projects?id=25&project_id=24&access_token=#{TOKEN}") do |response|
    result_data = BW::JSON.parse(response.body)
    delegate.load_data(result_data)
    delegate.view.reloadData
  end
end
```

Don't forget to reload your data, if you are importing into a table view controller.

Notice that the delegate is calling a load_data method, so make sure your view controller implements that:

```
class ProjectsController < UIViewController

  #...

  Projects.load_projects(self)

  #...

  def load_data(data)
    @projects ||= data
  end
  #...
end
```

Then do whatever you want with @projects

Comment: Thank you! I am on my way but unfortunately I cannot use the data returned. Please see my updated question above.

Comment: This is already outside the scope of this particular question, but I would suggest you debug @person to make sure it is the correct object you expect, since the error message says its a nil object.

Comment: mm, not sure what you mean? What is @person? The point with the load_data method is to be able to use @projects in the rest of the controller, right?

Comment: sorry I meant to say @project

Comment: I hope that answered your question.